# Static Block goes missing from home page

Tags: cms, static-block

I have a Static Block that I've created.  When I flush Magento cache, I see the static block on my home page which is what I want.  However, if I come back the next day, my static block is missing.  Do you have any suggestions on what to do?

Thank you!